# Bootstrap classes leaves some blank spaces i need to remove

Tags: css, class, magento, edit

i am dealing with a situation which i believe has to do with bootstrap classes.
I have a section in my Magento 2 website which goes as follow:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jKub3.png)

That blank space behind "Document/Trace 1" has to go. The thing is i have tried different strategies but none of them seems to work.
The code goes as follow:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HT5SN.png)

As you can see, the layout of the template is edited in the Magento Admin, but i believe if i edit the bootstrap classes i might be able to solve the problem. I guess maybe the classes are trying to cover the space on the container?
Every help is welcomed. Thank you very much.

Comment: Welcome to Stack overflow Alan , 
please post your code rather than a snapshot  of it

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with minimum height like below ?

```
.panel-body{
    .form-group{
        min-height:100px;
        height100%;
    }
}
```